# How to call private method by other methods?

Tags: methods, call, private, invoke

I am confused of calling a private method by another method(public) belonging to the same `class.Once` I have been told I gotta create an object of that class and then call the private method via this object but in one of my questions in this forum I have been told that I dont need to use object.

```
public class Train() {

    private void method1{......method definition..... }

    public void method2{......how to invoke method1??}

}
```

Can I simply call the first method inside the second method by using `method1();`  or should I invoke it by creating an object of the class and `Object_of_Train.method1();`.

Which one should I use?

Comment: What language is this? (I think they meant to say you need an *instance* of the class to invoke the method, since non-static methods operate on instances of a class. You don't drive cars generally, you drive *a* car. So if you want to drive, you need *a* car.)

Comment: it is java.so if the both methods were public then i could invoke one from the other without the need of an object but in this case since the first method is private i gotta use an object of that class to be able to call it from method 2???

Comment: You can't drive a car without a car. It's not a matter of protection, it's a matter of the logic of a method -- an instance method is invoked on an instance of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the class you should be able to call method1();

Outside the class you will need to call it from an instance of that class and will have access to public methods only

Comment: So you mean, if the methods are in the same class, one can be called by the other without the need of an object even if one or both of them are private, right?

Comment: are we talking about java?  
Within the same class public and private will make no difference to you. What seems to get you confused is the use of static, you may wanna look into it.

Comment: yeah it is about java. i got confused coz i ve been told that inside the main method i gotta create an object of the same class so that i can call the methods of this class.That s why i thought that this should also be applied on the other methods of that class.So can we say that if there are several methods are in one class and if i wanna call one of them by another one,it is not important if they are private or not,i can call them just by using the name like method1();    ....and also it s not important if they are static or non-static when we invoke inside the same class, am i right ?

Comment: I think the recommendation made to you was about creating an instance reference for use from a public static method. 
Example: YourClass.instanceObject.nonStaticMethod()

Comment: Yes, you're right.it was for public static void main(String args[]) but for the non-static ones i dont need to use the object of the class.it doesnt give an error if i call it simply by the method name.And could you please tell me the reason of this? why do we need to use an object to call a method of the same class by a static method ?

Comment: when calling myObject.doFunStuff(); you actually provide myObject as a scope for the method to run. In a static method, the scope is not provided since you just call MyObjectClass.doStaticCoolShit(); Therefore you get an error here because the method doesn't know where to apply, unless there is an instance reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.method1();` to call from method2() or any other non-static method in the class.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the private methods of a class using java reflection package.

**Step1 − Instantiate the Method class of the java.lang.reflect package by passing the method name of the method which is declared private.

Step2 − Set the method accessible by passing value true to the setAccessible() method.

Step3 − Finally, invoke the method using the invoke() method.**

Example

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class DemoTest {
   private void sampleMethod() {
      System.out.println("hello");
   }
}

public class SampleTest {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      Class c = Class.forName("DemoTest");
      Object obj = c.newInstance();
      Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("sampleMethod", null);
      method.setAccessible(true);
      method.invoke(obj, null);
   }
}
```

Source : [Tutorialpoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Can-private-methods-of-a-class-be-accessed-from-outside-of-a-class-in-Java)

Comment: This should be discouraged. Using reflection to call private methods is only for specialized and advanced use cases. Private methods are marked private for good reasons - to prevent them from being called that way. This answer should come with a disclaimer and it doesn't seem to answer the OP.